# Export Excel with images in a row's cell

Tags: .net, excel

I need coding a feature (using .NET): Export a table(in web) to excel. But with a table's cell which contains images (see the below picture), I wonder that in excel, a row's cell can contain images? That's mean: a cell contains both of text and image.

[image: Images in cell]

Please help me. And give me some guideline. Thanks.

Comment: which GRID control are you using in your web application? is this ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Excel can't really place an image inside a cell (maybe in 2007+ you can?), but you can certainly add images to an Excel spreadsheet using OLE automation, and you can even place them where they should be (there are methods that get you the pixel coordinates of a certain cell). So, the image isn't contained by the cell, but it can sit overlapping to the cell, but it won't "respond" to resizing rows / columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easy with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), but as M.A. Hanin said images are not stored in the cell but you can set coordinates inside cell, here is the example code :

```
  ExcelPackage ePack = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("Book1.xlsx"));
  ExcelWorksheet ws = ePack.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
  ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("Image1", new FileInfo("Test.png"));
  pic.SetPosition(0, 0, 0, 0);
  ePack.SaveAs(new FileInfo("BookWithPic.xlsx"));
```